# random.choice prints always the same result

Tags: python, minio

i'm pretty new to python but i know how to use most of the things in it, included random.choice. I want to choose a random file name from 2 files [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeMzN.jpg).

To do so, i'm using this line of code:

```
minio = Minio('myip',
                access_key='mykey',
                secret_key='mykey',
              )

images = minio.list_objects('mybucket', recursive=True)

for img2 in images:
    names = img2.object_name

print(random.choice([names]))
```

Everytime i try to run it, it prints always the same file's name *(c81d9307-7666-447d-bcfb-2c13a40de5ca.png)*

I tried to put the "print" function in the "for" block, but it prints out both of the files' names

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly what `images` is, but it seems to me that you set `names` to be a single thing. Then your pick a random element from the *one-element list* `[names]`.

Comment: "images" is the list of the objects uploaded to my database. I want to pick a random file's name from that list

Comment: Then you might wanna do `random.choice(images).object_name` instead. You're currently defining `names` to be first the first object in `images`, then the second, etc., so at the end  of the loop, `names` is the (name of the) *last* object in `images`. You then select a random element in the *one-element* list `[names]`, which obviously must give that single element.

Comment: Now it gives me this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mattia Antonacci/Desktop/Robe/MinioRipetra/test1.py", line 17, in <module>
    images = random.choice(immagini).object_name
  File "C:\Users\Mattia Antonacci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\random.py", line 288, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()`

Comment: So `images` is in fact *not* a list then.

Comment: i've solved the problem with @JakobVinkas 's answer, thank you too for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the variable `names` to one specific instsance of images right now.  That means it is only a single value. Try adding them to an array or similar instead.

For example:

```
names = [img2.object_name for img2 in images]

print(random.choice(names))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
minio = Minio('myip',
                access_key='mykey',
                secret_key='mykey',
              )

images = minio.list_objects('mybucket', recursive=True)
names = []

for img2 in images:
    names.append(img2.object_name)

print(random.choice([names]))
```

Try this, the problem may that your names was not list varible

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose one of the file names, try this :

```
minio = Minio('myip',
                access_key='mykey',
                secret_key='mykey',
              )

images = minio.list_objects('mybucket', recursive=True)

names = []
for img2 in images:
    names.append(img2.object_name)

print(random.choice(names))
```

The first code tries to randomly select a value from the array, `[names]`, but this only contain a single value, the value of the `names` variable after the last iteration of the for loop. Instead of doing that, create an array, `names` and append the values of `img2.object_name` from each iteration of the for loop to this array. And use this array to get the random name.

Answer (score 0):

Your `names` is just a simple variable that contains the most recently seen image name, rather than a list full of them.

The very last line of your script works as the one below:

```
value = 2
print(random.choice([value]))
```

which always prints 2. To get what you want, you need a list of all images. Here is your code with a simple fix:

```
names = []
for img2 in images:
    names.append(img2.object_name)

print(random.choice(names))
```

These code can be made considerably shorter with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
names = [img2.object_name for img2 in images]
print(random.choice([names]))
```